# Include square brackets in regex

Tags: regex, brackets, square-bracket

I want to generate a regex that will allow the exact string "[TEST]".
What is the required regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is as follows:

```
"\\[TEST\\]"
```

→ double escape each square bracket